# Is there an ORM library for Golang that support multiple schemas of Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm looking for an ORM library for Golang that supports working with multiple [Postgresql schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html).

The idea is to support [multi-tenancy using Postgres schemas](https://influitive.io/our-multi-tenancy-journey-with-postgres-schemas-and-apartment-6ecda151a21f). (i.e. upon each request, check which tenant should be queried and dynamically set the schema before querying)

Is anyone familiar with such a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that I've only used the standard library so far and therefore my assumption that an ORM will behave in the same manner as the `database/sql` package might very well be wrong.

---

I believe any ORM that exposes an interface analogous to the [standard one](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) that allows you to execute plain sql statements, like [xorm](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-xorm/xorm#Engine.Exec) and [gorm](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Exec) for example do, should be able to facilitate switching between schemas by setting the `search_path`.

```
db.Exec("SET search_path TO tenant_schema_123")
```

This sets the schema for the [db handle](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) and any successive queries using that db handle are made to `tenant_schema_123`.